# Hibernate: querying for a range of dates

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, orm

So my table contains a date column and I want to be able to return all rows where the date in this column falls between and including two dates given.

In addition I currently am using createCriteria(Car car) passing through the domain object to return a result set that matches the values I put in.

Example:

```
Car car
car.setColor("blue");

session.createCriteria(car);

.....
```

The above correctly returns all cars that are blue so now I want to build on this by returning all cars that are blue and have a manufacture date from say 1st January 2009 to 2nd December 2013.

Can anyone instruct me onto the correct way of implementing this using hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### use `Restrictions.between`:

`session.createCriteria(car)` return a `Critera` object,this object has a method [add](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#add%28org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion%29) whose pararmeter is a [Criterion](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion.html) object.And factory methods [Restrictions.between](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#between(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) produce such a object.

Comment: much obliged kind sir!